# NVARCHAR sorting in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

How can I sort:

```
BAR 1
BAR 2
BAR 3
BAR 4
BAR 11
BAR 12
```

in this order instead of getting

```
BAR 1
BAR 11
BAR 12
BAR 2
BAR 3
BAR 4
```

when I sort it in the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either left pad with zero(s),  Or add a sort order column.

Comment: I would prefer not to alter the data.

Comment: You don't need to alter the data; create a view with a left padded column of your data. Sort on that.